# VBA: Arrays with values from x to x rows

Tags: arrays, vba, dynamic

Suppose that in another cell I have A. So what I want is to for A I will bring into array1 = Array("0","80") and array2 = Array("100","240"). But it has to return array1,array2 in the same order of values, that is, 0, 80, 100, 240.

```
A  0   100
B  25  75
A  80  240
B  30  90
```

I was thinking about working with ranges, for instance, it will look into the table for example the 2 first columns and then if A = A then it will add all the values from 2nd column matching A in array1 and then all the values from 3rd column matching A in array2. Or is it better to work with cells positions?

Hope to hear news from you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd better work with arrays directly:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim dataArr As Variant
    Dim nFounds As Long, iArr As Long
    Dim myVal As Variant

    myVal = Range("E1").Value '<--| set "E1" to your actual "another cell" address

    With Worksheets("data") '<--| change "data" to your actual worksheet name
        dataArr = .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With

    ReDim array1(1 To UBound(dataArr)) As Variant, array2(1 To UBound(dataArr)) As Variant
    For iArr = 1 To UBound(dataArr)
        If dataArr(iArr, 1) = myVal Then
            array1(nFounds + 1) = dataArr(iArr, 2)
            array2(nFounds + 1) = dataArr(iArr, 3)
            nFounds = nFounds + 1
        End If
    Next
    If nFounds > 0 Then ReDim Preserve array1(1 To nFounds) As Variant, array2(1 To nFounds) As Variant
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the nFounds variable? Btw, it gives run tiime 1004 error.

Comment: `nFounds` counts the number of matches in array column 1. BTW: what line is throwing the error?

Comment: it's the one that remains highlighted when you press "Debug" button in your error messagebox

Comment: It's strange because none of the lines remains highlighted

Comment: it can be either yellow or blue highlighted. Otherwise step through your code: place your cursor inside any valid statement of the macro and press F8 to have it start, then press F8 to step through each subsequent code line until you reach the offending one

Comment: dataArr = .Range("C13", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value

But before the .Range I had to add the sh1.

Comment: what's the range of data you showed in your question? What's `sh1`?

Comment: The "E1" in your code is on sheet 3 but it has to check the table on sheet 1.

Comment: my `Range("E1").Value` has no worksheet qualification, hence it references the _active_ sheet. If you need it to point to "sheet 3 " just substitute `myVal = Range("E1").Value` with `myVal = Worksheets("Sheet 3").Range("E1").Value`. What's your actual "data" range address?  You may want to post some screenshots. Did you follow the comments in my code?

Comment: Yes i did. I will add those suggestions to my code. And will give some news soon.

Comment: In your code, how does it print the values on cells in a row? 

It will start with:

A  0   100
B  25  75
A  80  240
B  30  90

Then, if A = A it will return
A  0   100
A  80  240

And then, it will return
0   100
80  240

And then it will print:
D8:0
E8: 80
F8: 100
G8: 240

That's what I am trying to do. May be I haven't explained properly above.

Comment: As 
It is a matrix of arrays as shown in the example of my question that will be reducing its size step by step until having the following results in cells: D8: second_array(1,1) = 0, E8: second_array(3,1) = 80, F8: third_array(1,1) = 100, G8: third_array(3,1) = 240.

It will return the first and third position once A (value presented in the sheet 3) equals the value of first_array (sheet 1).

Comment: user3598756, I got it and your way is much complex but I admit I haven't explain properly. Its much simpler than that. You have to put the values of each column in each array. Then, you just require to move the cells positions to introduce the data since i am working with 2 different sheets. First define each range and the convert it to an array. Create a for loop from 1st position to the last position of one of the arrays. Then it print the values on the excel sheet.

Comment: Well you know what to do, then you can take my code and twist it to your needs. And should you get stuck you could make a new question posting it along with its issues

Comment: @vbalearner, if my answer solved your question, you may want to mark it as accepted. thank you